# when I click gridview paging it is hiding total grid itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

No update panel used but grid exist in content page . when I click any page number in paging total grid is hiding. No update panel used but grid exist in content page. when I click any page number in paging total grid is hiding:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdViewMasterTable" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="GrdViewMasterTable_RowEditing"
        OnRowUpdating="GrdViewMasterTable_RowUpdating"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdViewMasterTable_RowCancelingEdit"
        AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="15"
        OnPageIndexChanging="GrdViewMasterTable_PageIndexChanging"
        HorizontalAlign="Left"
        OnRowDataBound="GrdViewMasterTable_RowDataBound"
        OnRowDeleting="GrdViewMasterTable_RowDeleting"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
        SkinID="GridViewList">
        <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric"
            Position="Bottom"
            PageButtonCount="10" />
        <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" HorizontalAlign="Center" />


    </asp:GridView>
```

When I click any page numner in paging total grid is hiding:

```
protected void GrdViewMasterTable_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (GrdViewMasterTable.EditIndex != -1)
        {
            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
            if (confirmValue == "Yes")
            {
                Update();
                GrdViewMasterTable.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                GrdViewMasterTable.DataBind();
                //FillGridFromViewState();
                //FillGridFromDataTable();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Clear the error message.
            errorMessage = string.Empty;
            GrdViewMasterTable.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

                GrdViewMasterTable.DataBind();


            //FillGridFromViewState();
            //FillGridFromDataTable();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        AlertMsg(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.visible(v=vs.110).aspx)

CustomerGridView.PagerSettings.Visible = true;

Comment: Where I have to add this? I was added in GrdViewMasterTable_PageIndexChanging . still same issue

Answer (score 0):

try below one:

```
void GrdViewMasterTable_RowEditing(Object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    // Hide the pager row.
    GrdViewMasterTable.PagerSettings.Visible = true;
  }
```